# Crashlytics error : "seems like your kit is not activating"

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have integrated `crashlytics` into my app. But I am stuck in this.

[image]

What would be the reason for this?
Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: see this https://twittercommunity.com/t/ios-seems-like-your-kit-isnt-activating/55077/6

Comment: Thanks. But I have already added that line to my application didfinishlaunchwithoption. Also I enabled the debug mode=yeas before that line. And I tried xcode restartig as well as the fabric. But still same.

Comment: Can you share the content of your console output from a run of the app with Fabric debug mode enabled?

Comment: @MikeBonnell Thanks for your response. Just now it solved. I did run it on my device then I got an email called active. I enabled a force crash at my splash screen viewdidload. Still i'm waiting for the crash report. My records are empty on dashboard.

Comment: Make sure you relaunch the app post-crash to send the report. Also, note if you're testing on the Simulator or with your device connected to Xcode, you need to stop Xcode's debugger: https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/test-crash.html#troubleshooting

Comment: I faced the same. I just quit Xcode and fabric. Login into fabric and choose project, copy script then open Xcode and paste there and build the project.